# How to make the SubView of a UIView, placed out of UIView frame, interactive?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have added a `UIView` to a View of a View Controller. Say:

```
CGRect paneRect = {10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f, 50.0f};
UIView *pane = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:paneRect];
pane.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
pane.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
pane.clipsToBounds = NO;
[self.view addSubview:pane];
```

Then I've added a UIButton to `pane`:

```
CGRect testRect = {10.0f, 25.0f, pane.frame.size.width - 20.0f, 50.0f};
UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[test setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[test setFrame:testRect];
[pane addSubview:test];
```

Now half of the "test" button is within the pane and the other half is out. The upper half is interactive and responds to touches however the lower half is not.

[image]

Is it possible to make the whole "test" button interactive and touchable instead of its half?

Comment: You can add `test` to the `self.view` anyway, unless you have some other requirement...

Comment: Hi @DixitPatel, I gave your answer a try but that does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @nhahtdh In fact this is an indirect question to a bigger one. I'm developing an **Auto-Complete Text Field** and as the suggestion table-view is drawn under the text-field, I'm trying to make it a subview of the text field. everything works fine except UITableView which not receives touch events and I do not know how to deal with that.

Comment: @anonim.developer: There is no need for the table view to be subview of text field. You only need to make it appears under the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to make these view stick with each other then you can do some thing like this

```
CGRect mainViewRect = {10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f, 75.0f};
UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainViewRect];
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mainView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mainView];

CGRect paneRect = {0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 50.0f};
UIView *pane = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:paneRect];
pane.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
pane.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
pane.clipsToBounds = NO;
[mainView addSubview:pane];



CGRect testRect = {10.0f, 25.0f, pane.frame.size.width - 20.0f, 50.0f};
UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[test setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[test setFrame:testRect];
[mainView addSubview:test];
```

Comment: I'm developing an **Auto-Complete Text Field** and as the suggestion table-view is drawn under the text-field, I'm trying to make it a subview of the text field. everything works fine except UITableView which not receives touch events and I do not know how to deal with that. I think finally I have to follow your solution some how.

Answer (score 0):

just do Like this Way

```
CGRect paneRect = {10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f, 50.0f};
UIView *pane = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:paneRect];
pane.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
pane.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
pane.clipsToBounds = NO;
[self.view addSubview:pane];


CGRect testRect = {10.0f, 25.0f, pane.frame.size.width - 20.0f, 50.0f};
UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[test setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
test.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[test setFrame:testRect];
[pane addSubview:test];
```

For Action of UIButton just add

```
[test addTarget:self action:@selector(processButtonCLick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you want to uibutton center of pane Add

```
 test.center =pane.center;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but after applying that `test` button now is not interactive at all. In fact `test` button is a subview of 'pane' view. if `pane` set to not being interactive none of its children receives touch events (I guess of course)